# Pegar posição especifica no .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiz um laço `.each` que retorna alguns `button`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            listarPedidos()
            var consultas = setInterval(listarPedidos, 4000);

        });
        function listarPedidos(){
            $.getJSON('conectar/_pedidos/listaPedidos.php', function (data) {  
                $.each(data, function(i, valor){
                  elementoFILA += "<tr id='statusFILA'>";
                    elementoFILA += "<td>" + valor.PED_ID + "</td>";
                    elementoFILA += "<td>" + valor.PED_DATA_N + "</td>";
                    elementoFILA += "<td>" + resultado + " / " + valor.CLI_TEL + "</td>";
                    elementoFILA += "<button class='btn btn-info' id='btnVisu' title='Visualizar Pedido'><i class='fas fa-eye'></i> </button>";
                    elementoFILA += "<button class='btn btn-primary' title='Editar Pedido'><i class='fa fa-pencil-alt'></i> </button>";
                    elementoFILA += "<button class='btn btn-dark' disabled='' title='Setar Saiu Entrega'><i class='fa fa-motorcycle'></i> </button>";
                    elementoFILA += "<button class='btn btn-dark' id='btnFinalizar' disabled='' title='Finalizar Pedido'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> </button>";
                    elementoFILA += '</div></td>'
                 elementoFILA += "</tr>";
  }
```

Minha dificuldade é pegar linha `id='btnVisu'`.

Estou tentando fazer dessa forma, mas não da certo:

```
$('#btnVisu').click(function () {
   alert("clicou");
});
```

Sei que tem que pegar o contador do `.each` mas não consegui fazer.

Comment: Seu laço está gerando vários elementos com o mesmo `id`. Logo, o `.click` vai ser aplicado apenas ao primeiro `#btnVisu`... Teve uma pergunta praticamente idêntica à sua esses dias. Vou ver se acho e linko aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O teu problema é que estás a gerar IDs duplicados. Em HTML IDs têm de ser únicos, e por isso quando usas o seletor só vais receber o primeiro elemento com essa ID.

Tens pelo menos 3 soluções:

- usar classes
- usar IDs únicos
- criar um elemento dentro do `.each` diretamente

---

#### Usando classes:

Em vêz de `id='btnVisu'` usa `<button class='btn btn-info btnVisu'` e depois `$('.btnVisu').click(` no auscultador do evento.

#### Usando IDs únicos:

Usa `id='btnVisu" + i + "'` (incrementando com o numero da posição dentro do array) e depois usas esse ID no `.click()``

#### Criando elementos dentro do `.each`

Evita todos os IDs duplicados. Neste caso o código poderia ser assim:

```js
function visualizar() {
  console.log(this);
}

$.each(data, function(i, valor) {
  let elementoFILA = '';
  elementoFILA += "<td>" + valor.PED_ID + "</td>";
  elementoFILA += "<td>" + valor.PED_DATA_N + "</td>";
  elementoFILA += "<td>" + resultado + " / " + valor.CLI_TEL + "</td>";
  elementoFILA += "<button class='btn btn-info' title='Visualizar Pedido'><i class='fas fa-eye'></i> </button>";
  elementoFILA += "<button class='btn btn-primary' title='Editar Pedido'><i class='fa fa-pencil-alt'></i> </button>";
  elementoFILA += "<button class='btn btn-dark' disabled='' title='Setar Saiu Entrega'><i class='fa fa-motorcycle'></i> </button>";
  elementoFILA += "<button class='btn btn-dark btnFinalizar' disabled='' title='Finalizar Pedido'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> </button>";
  elementoFILA += '</td>'
  const $tr = $('<tr />');
  $tr.appendTo('table'); // ou outro seletor/elemento
  $tr.html(elementoFILA);
  $tr.find('.btn-info').click(visualizar);
});
```

**Nota:** no teu HTML tens `elementoFILA += '</div></td>'`. Não vejo onde essa `<div>` começa. Será que ficou esquecida?

Comment: Obrigado Sergio pela ajuda. Então fiz com classe deu mesma coisa, e com id unico  como eu pegaria no $('#btnVisu?').click(function () o codigo aqui? e outra coisa vc disse que ele pega o primeiro da listagem porem nem o primeiro ta pegando dessa forma que estou fazendo, ai achei que estava colocando o codigo em local errado, ai peguei um outro id so pra testa fora do each ai ele funciona beleza